# How does the brain distinguish between single or multiple sounds?

Tags: psychoacoustics

On a piano "for tenor and treble notes, three strings are strung for each key, and for bass notes, the number of strings per note decreases from three, to two, and then to one as you approach the lowest bass notes". Despite this, we always perceive a single note when we press a single piano key. What makes multiple sounds (like that of a treble piano key) appear as a single sound?

What characteristics of an artificially generated waveform reproduced by a single speaker cause it to be perceived as a single sound or instead as a collection of distinct sounds played together?